# git bash can't pull or push from bitbucket or github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a problem with git bash. When I am trying to pull from **bitbucket.org** it asks me password and after I entered password I got an error:

> fatal: unable to access https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/repository_name.git/
>   Empty reply from server

I also tried **SourceTree** but I got the same error...

I cannot find a good solution ... 
Does someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Looks like a problem with git cache. I deleted git.cache from .git directory and everything started working properly after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue , restarting SourceTree will solve the problem.